# Dropbox folder permissions changing to 700 and causing re-sync

Tags: macos, permissions, apache-http-server, dropbox, osx-mavericks

I've just got myself a new Macbook Pro 13" running Mavericks, my first experience of OSX 10.9 having moved up from an older mac running 10.7.

After setting up my local web development environment and my hosts and vhosts settings etc, plus my local sites files which live inside my dropbox sync folder, everything is working well.

However, twice in the last week for some unknown reason my dropbox folder permissions have suddenly changed from 755 to 700. I haven't been able to identify a trigger.

This causes two problems - firstly my local sites don't work, I get a permission denied error, and secondly Dropbox thinks everything (yes, all 50Gb of it...) in my dropbox folder has changed so it has to resync and upload everything. Yikes.

When this happens I have to change the dropbox folder back to 755 to get my sites working again.

My dropbox folder is in Users/username/ along with Applications and Desktop folders etc - I notice all the other folders are 700 too.

So my question(s) is/are:

- Have I set up my local dev environment incorrectly?
- Should the dropbox folder be 700 too, and if so how can I allow access to apache for my sites to work?
- What could be causing the permissions switch, and can I prevent it?

Thanks in advance